# What is Intel rapid start technology and how can i enable it?

Tags: ssd, intel-rapid-start

I am wondering about Intel's rapid start technology. How can i enable it? Does it affect the start up and boot speed of my PC.

Does it require any special hardware like SSD?

Comment: First of all heartily thanks.

I've read the article from the Intel support team. and yes I've Intel 3rd gen core i5-3470 processor with Intel rapid start technology. But how to enable it. what drivers does it require. Also i heard that this feature require a special partition. Is it true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intel Rapid Start Technology is a hybrid sleep mode that allows a very quick resume. Once configured it is activated by sending your computer into a sleep mode (S3 state), which triggers a process that saves your computer's state, much like hibernation. Once the process is complete the computer is effectively powered off, however powering the computer on will result in a process returning the computer to the sleep state very quickly, and then resuming from that sleep state returning you to wherever you were when you sent the computer to sleep.

Before altering your computer's configuration in any way, please read the Intel user manual for Rapid Start Technology, which can be found at http://download.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/sb/rapid_start_technology_user_guide.pdf

The Intel download page for their Rapid Start Technology service and user interface for a number of desktop motherboards can be found at https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=21612

Make sure to check that your hardware matches one of the items on that list before downloading, and take the steps indicated in the user's manual before installing.

Comment: Thanks, i found your answer useful.
But my motherboard is Asus P8H61 R2.0. Do you have any knowledge where can i find the same app for my board.

Comment: ASUS provides a version of Intel Rapid Start Technology for that motherboard at http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/misc/sata/IRSS_V1001015_Win7.zip

Comment: The manual link is now dead. Do you have any idea what the hardware requirements for this are? I’m guessing you need a compatible motherboard. Does your SSD drive also need to be compatible?